# AllJoyn - How to make bbclient ping bbservice when they are running on different Linux devices that are connected through Ethernet cable

Tags: alljoyn

AllJoyn framework version 15.09.00a is used to build bbservice and bbclient applications on Linux platform for performing these tests below.

If bbservice and bbclient are run on the same Linux device with the following commands

```
bbservice -n com.test &
bbclient -n com.test -d -c 5 &
```

then bbclient can ping bbservice 5 times successfully.

Below is output of this test.

```
bbservice -n com.test &

AllJoyn Library version: v15.09.00
AllJoyn Library build info: AllJoyn Library v15.09.00 (Built Mon Feb 29 22:13:06 UTC 2016)
opts.transports = 0x105
bbservice com.test ready to accept connections


bbclient -n com.test -d -c 5 &

AllJoyn Library version: v15.09.00
AllJoyn Library build info: AllJoyn Library v15.09.00 (Built Mon Feb 29 22:13:06 UTC 2016)
FindAdvertisedName 0x100 takes 54 ms
FoundAdvertisedName(name=com.test, transport=0x100, prefix=com.test)
FindAdvertisedName 0x4 takes 66 ms
FoundAdvertisedName(name=com.test, transport=0x4, prefix=com.test)
Accepting JoinSession request from :9-ewflpc.2
Accepting JoinSession request from :9-ewflpc.2
NameOwnerChanged(:okSgAM9h.1, null, :okSgAM9h.1)
Session Established: joiner=:9-ewflpc.2, sessionId=e78616c5
NameOwnerChanged(:okSgAM9h.2, null, :okSgAM9h.2)
NameOwnerChanged(com.test, null, :okSgAM9h.2)
Session Established: joiner=:9-ewflpc.2, sessionId=e80376f3
Link timeout was successfully set to 10
JoinSession 0x4 takes 72 ms
Sending "Ping String 1" to org.alljoyn.alljoyn_test.my_ping synchronously
JoinSession 0x100 takes 76 ms
Pinged with: Ping String 1
Link timeout was successfully set to 10
com.test.my_ping ( path=/org/alljoyn/alljoyn_test ) returned "Ping String 1"
Sending "Ping String 2" to org.alljoyn.alljoyn_test.my_ping synchronously
Pinged with: Ping String 2
com.test.my_ping ( path=/org/alljoyn/alljoyn_test ) returned "Ping String 2"
Sending "Ping String 3" to org.alljoyn.alljoyn_test.my_ping synchronously
Pinged with: Ping String 3
com.test.my_ping ( path=/org/alljoyn/alljoyn_test ) returned "Ping String 3"
Sending "Ping String 4" to org.alljoyn.alljoyn_test.my_ping synchronously
Pinged with: Ping String 4
com.test.my_ping ( path=/org/alljoyn/alljoyn_test ) returned "Ping String 4"
Sending "Ping String 5" to org.alljoyn.alljoyn_test.my_ping synchronously
Pinged with: Ping String 5
com.test.my_ping ( path=/org/alljoyn/alljoyn_test ) returned "Ping String 5"
com.test.GetProperty ( path=/org/alljoyn/alljoyn_test) returned "100"
SessionLost(e78616c5) was called. Reason = 2.
SessionLost(e80376f3) was called. Reason = 2.
bbclient exiting with status 0 (ER_OK)
```

If bbservice is run on Linux device with IP address is 192.168.1.1 and bbclient is run on another Linux device with IP address is 192.168.1.2 then bbclient cannot find and ping bbservice. These two Linux devices are connected by Ethernet cable, and they can ping each other successufly with Linux ping command.

Below is output of this test.

(On 192.168.1.1 Linux device)

```
bbservice -n com.test &

AllJoyn Library version: v15.09.00
AllJoyn Library build info: AllJoyn Library v15.09.00 (Built Mon Feb 29 22:13:06 UTC 2016)
opts.transports = 0x105
bbservice com.test ready to accept connections
```

(On 192.168.1.2 Linux device)

```
bbclient -n com.test -d -c 5 &

AllJoyn Library version: v15.09.00
AllJoyn Library build info: AllJoyn Library v15.09.00 (Built Mon Feb 29 22:13:06 UTC 2016)
```

So what need to be done to make bbclient can ping bbservice when they are run on different Linux devices.

Thanks,

P. Tran

Answer (score 0):

There are network issues on Linux devices that make bbclient cannot ping bbservice when they are running on these Linux devices.

After network issues are fixed, bbclient can ping bbservice sucessfully.

Thanks,

P. Tran